# Does the granite countertop on my deck require separate footings?

Tags: framing, deck, joists, decking, granite

If I want to have a granite countertop as a table on top of my deck, do I need to support the 4 corners with actual footing, like 4x4 with concrete? Or it is possible to just bold the 4 legs on the side of the joists?

I have not weight my granite yet but according to this, it is 12.8 lbs sq ft

http://www.allstilesinc.com/granite-tiles-faqs/41-granite-pre-sales-questions/70-how-much-does-granite-weigh.html

Mine is like 3' x 9'

I am inspired by this, as I have no design yet.

[image]

I don't have the grill in my case but the countertop will be close to the railing. So for 4 corners of the 9  foot long countertop, are they supported by footing below? Or the legs are just standing on top of the joists underneath?
**UPDATE 1**

This is a free standing deck. Conveniently, two legs of the countertop if supported by the posts already. So the question is do I need the other 2 legs supported by posts? Or can they just sit on top of 2x8 joists that are on top of 4x8 beam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your deck is somewhat modern and properly designed and built, it can easily handle a live load of 13 pounds per square foot (no extra footings required, no need to worry about aligning the table legs over joists, etc).

That said, I am assuming your deck is somewhat modern and properly built.
You should consider paying a structural engineer to take a look at your deck (especially the ledger connection to the house, which is a typical weak spot).  That would be a lot cheaper than pouring new footings and going crazy overbuilding it, plus it will give you a piece of mind.  You might be surprised how inexpensive a structural engineer costs to take a look at your deck and give an opinion.

Comment: Hi I have updated my question with more information. This is a new construction so I can pour as many footing as I want. It's actually easier thay way in a sense.

Comment: Okay, if it adheres to the IRC standard (assuming you are in the U.S.), then it will have 10 psf dead load capability and 40 psf live load capability _minimum_.   And most decks are stronger than that.   13 psf would not really need special footings.  You might consider using 6x6 posts with thicker joists, to beef up your deck though.